# How to disable clicking on TabbedPage menu item when hidden in Xamarin Forms Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an XF application that hides the `TabbedPage` menu when a user in the Quiz mode and show it again when the user stops the quiz mode. Below is the code on how I hide and show the menu:

```
public static void ClearNav()
{
   navHomeTabPage.Icon = "";
   navHomeTabPage.Title = "";
   // more items
}

public static void SetNav()
{
   navHomeTabPage.Icon = "home.png";
   navHomeTabPage.Title = "Home";
   // more items
}
```

With this I am able to hide the menu items but they are still clickable. Is there any way to disable this clicking event in Xamarin.Android? I couldn't find any article/post about this. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am using `BottomNavigationView` to place my tab menu at the bottom.

```
public class BottomTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener
{
   private MainPage _page;
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
   {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);

      if (e.NewElement != null)
      {
          _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
      }
      else
      {
          _page = (MainPage)e.OldElement;
      }

      // More codes
   }

   bool BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
   {
      base.OnNavigationItemSelected(item);
      if (App.quizRunning == true)
      {
          _page.CurrentPage = App.navCardsTabPage;
      }
         return true;
   }

   void BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener.OnNavigationItemReselected(IMenuItem item)
   { 
      if (App.quizRunning == true)
      {
          _page.CurrentPage = App.navCardsTabPage;
      }
   }
```

The `App.navCardsTabPage` has the code for hiding and showing the tab items title and icon (`SetNav` and `ClearNav`).

Comment: I have added a custom renderer kindly take a look and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `IsEnabled="false"` Property and see if it works:

**Update:**

Add a class `BottomNavTabPageRenderer` which is your Android Custom Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BottomNavTabPage), typeof(BottomNavTabPageRenderer))]
namespace Droid.CustomRenderers
{
public class BottomNavTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener, BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemReselectedListener
{
    private bool _isShiftModeSet;

    public BottomNavTabPageRenderer( Context context )
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    bool BottomNavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener.OnNavigationItemSelected( IMenuItem item )
    {
        if(item.TitleFormatted.ToString().Trim()== "YourTitleString") // Disable based on Title of the item 
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!(this.Element as BottomNavTabPage).IsPageChangeEnabled) // Disable every tab
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void OnNavigationItemReselected( IMenuItem item )
    {

    }

    protected override void OnLayout( bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b )
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        try
        {
            if(!_isShiftModeSet)
            {
                var children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);

                if(children.SingleOrDefault(x => x is BottomNavigationView) is BottomNavigationView bottomNav)
                {
                    bottomNav.SetShiftMode(false, false);
                    _isShiftModeSet = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error setting ShiftMode: {e}");
        }
    }

    private List<View> GetAllChildViews( View view )
    {
        if(!(view is ViewGroup group))
        {
            return new List<View> { view };
        }

        var result = new List<View>();

        for(int i = 0; i < group.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = group.GetChildAt(i);

            var childList = new List<View> { child };
            childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));

            result.AddRange(childList);
        }

        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
 }
}
```

**Note in the `OnNavigationItemSelected` method there are two conditions based on the which you can set whether the tab in the page will be disabled or not.**

Add Bottom Navigation tabbed page class in your PCL project to use as a tab page

```
 public class BottomNavTabPage : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShiftingEnabledProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPageChangeEnabled),
                                                                typeof(bool),
                                                                typeof(BottomNavTabPage), false);

    public bool IsPageChangeEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShiftingEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShiftingEnabledProperty, value); }
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        this.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(IsPageChangeEnabled);
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    public BottomNavTabPage()
    {            
        this.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
    }
}
```

Add a Shift Mode for your Bottom Navigation View so that it shows you the label and the icon properly.

```
 public static void SetShiftMode( this BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView, bool enableShiftMode, bool enableItemShiftMode )
    {
        try
        {
            var menuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;
            if(menuView == null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to find BottomNavigationMenuView");
                return;
            }


            var shiftMode = menuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");

            shiftMode.Accessible = true;
            shiftMode.SetBoolean(menuView, enableShiftMode);
            shiftMode.Accessible = false;
            shiftMode.Dispose();


            for(int i = 0; i < menuView.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var item = menuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                if(item == null)
                    continue;

                item.SetShiftingMode(enableItemShiftMode);
                item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);

            }

            menuView.UpdateMenuView();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to set shift mode: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

Usage:

You can use this in C# and XAML like shown below:

**C#:**

```
BottomNavTabPage tabbedPage = null;
tabbedPage = new BottomNavTabPage();
tabbedPage.IsPageChangeEnabled=false; // Important for not allowing tab change
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
{
  Icon = "icon",
  Title = "Schedule"
};
var navigationPage2 = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
{
  Icon = "icon",
  Title = "Schedule2"
};

tabbedPage.Children.Add(navigationPage);
tabbedPage.Children.Add(navigationPage2);
this.MainPage= tabbedPage;
```

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Custom:BottomNavTabPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:XamarinCertUnderstanding.CustomControls"             
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
         x:Class="XamarinCertUnderstanding.Views.MainPage">
<Custom:TodayPage />
<NavigationPage Title="Schedule" Icon="schedule.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <Custom:SchedulePage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</Custom:BottomNavTabPage>
```

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy answer. I made some edits to my question please kindly check. Thanks

Comment: Do not worry it should still work after the code change that you have done

Comment: @iamsophia I am updating the code to use Bottom Navigation View kindly take a look

Comment: Again thank you for the lengthy answer but this does not work. The tabs would still be clickable.

Comment: What do you mean by tabs would still be click able? The tabs will have a click effect but the tab won't change

Answer (score 0):

I had, I think a very similar feature request regarding my applciation login mechanism, but with MenuItem in xamarin forms.
My scenario was similar to yours. When user logged in, I wanted to enable the Logout menuitem in the flyout and return to my app start page. Also, when User entered without login, then I wanted to Disable my Logout MenuItem.
( My application can be used without registration/login)

Regarding your scenario, you just hided the text with setting empty string to Title, but you did not disabled.

So the solution is to make your Menu.IsEnabled = false;

When I figured this out. I tried to bind my BaseViewModel.IsUserLoggedIn property to my MenuItem.IsEnabled property, but that is just didn't work for me. After some investigation, I found MenuItem.IsEnabled property is an internal property of the MenuItem. So, I had to find another way, which was the MessagingCenter.

How I used:

1. I found the place in my code, where I would like to send the message. It was a command in my ViewModel, but also I could use a clicked event for example from a button.

   ```
   MessagingCenter.Send<string>("ApplicationStartViewModel", "LoggedIn");
   ```
2. I found the place where I would like to get the message. For me it was my AppShell.xaml.cs contructor. (AppShell contains my MenuItem). So, I used:

   ```
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "LoggedIn", (sender) =>
        {
            LogoutMenuItem.IsEnabled = true;
        });

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "NotLoggedIn", (sender) =>
        {
            LogoutMenuItem.IsEnabled = false;                
        });
   ```
3. Of course before do that, I had to give a name to my MenuItem in my AppShell.xaml

   ```
     <MenuItem x:Name="LogoutMenuItem"                
               Text="Logout from user account."
               Command="{Binding ExecuteLogoutCommand}" >        
     </MenuItem>
   ```